# Reading value after every 1 seconds

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi

1. I have two raspberry pi. Suppose this two pi are denoted as A and B
2. So A and B are connected with each other over socket.
3. On particular event, A is generating value every one seconds.
   and on event A stops generating those values.

So B needs to read those values from A every 1 second over socket.
So B has while loop running 
So what I have done is that I am reading time every while loop iteration and checking whether 1 seconds elapsed or not. If 1 seconds elapsed, I am reading values from B.

Here is some pseudo code for this.

```
while True:
     on = read_from_A()

      if on:        // "on" will suggest me to start read from B
           current_time = time.time()
           if current_time - last_time == 1:
              read_values_from_A()
              last_time = current_time
           do_some_task()
```

With this approach I am not able to read read values from A **exact** after *1 seconds*. B is missing some values from A.

So suppose A generated 360 values in 6 minutes
B should be able to read those 360 values.

What is the way that I should be using so that there should not be any data loss.

Comment: Can't you just read with timeout, or better use async communication? Didn't work with _RPi_, but I see that you mentioned sockets: [select](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) module might help you.

Comment: Reading from sockets is not usually something that needs precise timing like this. B can happily read from the socket whenever it pleases, and will only receive data once A has written to it.

Comment: why are you not using `time.sleep(1)` ?